# How do I merge two arrays by comparing only specific keys?

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures, merge, array-merge

So I have two arrays - $twitterData and $facebookData.

$twitterData looks like

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [text] => Hello World http://somelink
        [type] => twitter
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [text] => We like to keep our developers happy! 
        [type] => twitter
    )
```

$facebookData looks like

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [text] => We like to keep our developers happy! http://somelink.com
            [type] => facebook
        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [text] => Take a look
            [type] => facebook
        )
```

I am trying to merge the two arrays together into one array called $socialFeed. The issue is I am trying to merge them in the way so lets say if the first 50 characters of the "text" key are the same for any two array items, then I would the merged array to only have that item show up once. So "We like to keep our developers happy! http://somelink.com" would appear once (instead of having one with the link and one without).

I have tried using both array_diff and array_intersect but they both compare the entire values of the keys instead of just the first X characters of the text key.

Comment: what structure do you want the target array to have? you indicate your source arrays

Comment: What should the result be?

Comment: you give the answer in your question. Create two derivative arrays with only the first X characters of text, and diff those. The diff routes between those derivative arrays is the same as the diff route for your original arrays

Comment: You'll have to roll your own. PHP's array functions are handy, and good at what they do, but they're not universal toys. If you wan to compare only subsets of array elements, then you're stuck with providing your own custom tools.

Comment: @b_dubb: The target/resulting array should have the same structure as the arrays posted above. Only difference is that if an item exists on both the type would be "both"

Answer (score 0):

use the value you want to have in common as array key, and push networks, if the entry already exists:

```
$feedResult = array();

foreach ($twitterPost AS $entry){
    $newKey = substr($entry["text"], 0 , 10); //first 10chars
    if (isset($feedResult[$newKey])){
       //actually this will never happen, because when iterating the FIRST
       //post array, there will be no entry. But doing so allows to swap arround
       //the processing order of networks.
       $feedResult[$newKey]["network"][] = "twitter"; //add another network
    }else{
       //create new entry
       $feedResult[$newKey] = array("network" => array("twitter"), "text" => $entry["text"]);
    }
}

foreach ($facebookPost AS $entry){
    $newKey = substr($entry["text"], 0 , 10); //first 10chars
    if (isset($feedResult[$newKey])){
       $feedResult[$newKey]["network"][] = "facebook"; //add another network
    }else{
       //create new entry
       $feedResult[$newKey] = array("network" => array("facebook"), "text" => $entry["text"]);
    }
}
```

finally you get something like (its untested, but the idea should be clear):

```
["Hello Worl"] => Array
(
  ["Text"] = "Hello World http://somelink"
  ["network"] => Array
  ( 
       [0] => "twitter" 
  )
)
["We like to"] => Array
(
  ["Text"] = "We like to keep our developers happy!"
  ["network"] => Array
  ( 
     [0] => "twitter",
     [1] => "facebook" 
  )
)
["Take a loo"] => Array
(
  ["Text"] = "Take a look"
  ["network"] => Array
  ( 
     [0] => "facebook" 
  )
)
```

An optimization would be to use a `md5()` hash of the COMPLETE text as new key. Then they are merged, when text values are equal - (or the hash colides, but thats another topic and most likely not going to happen for news-posts)

Answer (score 0):

i went ahead and baked up a class for you.  basically i loop through both arrays and create a new array containing only text data from both arrays.  after i create the new array (checking for existing array data with same text - no duplicates),i set boolean vars for each original array and i loop through the array of unique text strings and check each array for the text string.  if i find the text in one of the original array i change the boolean value for the corresponding original array.  i test the two boolean variables for values and set the new $socialArr values accordingly.  hope this makes sense.  code is tested and works.

```
<?php

class socialArray {

    public function init($twitter,$facebook){
        $this->combinedText = $this->combinedTextArr($twitter,$facebook);
        $this->socialArr = $this->makeSocialArr($twitter,$facebook);
        return $this->socialArr;
    }

    public function combinedTextArr($twitter,$facebook){
        $combinedText = array();
        foreach($twitter as $key => $value){
            if( !in_array($value["text"],$combinedText ) ){
                $combinedText[] = $value["text"];
            }
        }
        foreach($facebook as $key => $value){
            if( !in_array($value["text"],$combinedText ) ){
                $combinedText[] = $value["text"];
            }
        }
        return $combinedText;
    }

    public function makeSocialArr($twitter,$facebook){
        $socialArr = array();
        foreach($this->combinedText as $value){
            $twitterTest = false;
            $facebookTest = false;
            foreach($twitter as $var){
                if( $var["text"] == $value) {
                    $twitterTest = true;
                }
            }
            foreach($facebook as $var){
                if( $var["text"] == $value ) {
                    $facebookTest = true;
                }
            }
            if( $twitterTest === true && $facebookTest === false ) {
                $socialArr[] = array(
                                        'text' => $value,
                                        'type' => 'twitter'
                                    );
            } else if ( $twitterTest === false && $facebookTest === true ) {
                $socialArr[] = array(
                                        'text' => $value,
                                        'type' => 'facebook'
                                    );
            } else if ( $twitterTest === true && $facebookTest === true ) {
                $socialArr[] = array(
                                        'text' => $value,
                                        'type' => 'both'
                                    );
            }
        }
        return $socialArr;
    }

}


$facebook = array();

$facebook[] = array(
                    "text" => "A post on facebook with text and stuff",
                    "type" => "facebook"
                );

$facebook[] = array(
                    "text" => "This occurs in both arrays",
                    "type" => "facebook"
                );

$twitter = array();

$twitter[] = array(
                    "text" => "A tweet of the utmost importance",
                    "type" => "twitter"
                );

$twitter[] = array(
                    "text" => "This occurs in both arrays",
                    "type" => "twitter"
                );

$socArrMaker = new socialArray();
$socialArr = $socArrMaker->init($twitter,$facebook);

echo "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body{ font-family: sans-serif; }</style></head><body><pre>\r\n";
print_r($socialArr);
echo "</pre></body></html>\r\n";
```

which produces ...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => A tweet of the utmost importance
            [type] => twitter
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => This occurs in both arrays
            [type] => both
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [text] => A post on facebook with text and stuff
            [type] => facebook
        )

)
```

Comment: @raeq tested this and it seems to do what you require